# Compile scss and catch errors using problemMatcher in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, error-handling, gulp, vscode-tasks

I'm using gulp to compile `scss` to `css`:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('compileScss', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});
```

In `.tasks.json` I definded a task:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Gulp: build",
        "type": "gulp",
        "task": "build",
        "problemMatcher": []
    },
]
```

It's possible to catch somehow errors during scss compilation using `problemMatcher`?